# Media Queries not working properly to change the width

Tags: html, css

I am making this JS calculator project, which I want to make responsive. But it's not quite working properly.
I want to make the width of the .calculator slightly bigger when the screen becomes smaller because in the that way all the buttons can be shown properly(especially the operator ones). 
Here is the codepen I have worked on:https://codepen.io/tanjimanim/pen/jOwoYrV?editors=0110

and the media query I have written.

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 630px) {
  .calculator {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `min-width` works if range is outside that specified `px` value and `max-width` works for that specified range.

I think it is because you are setting `width:60%` for both device size.
and you are using `max-width:45px` property on `.calculator` class so need to change that property in media query and if you want width of your calculator to fit the width of the display size you can remove that property of `max-width`.
You should try:
works when size of display is in range of  320px and change width according to your need

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
  .calculator {
    max-width: 60%;
  }
}
```

works when size of display is greater than of 320px and change width according to your need

```
@media screen and(max-width: 320px) {
  .calculator {
    max-width: 60%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Now this was the answer I was looking for. I was wondering why the width is still not changing on my mobile display. So I changed the max-width to 40% and it worked! 
Btw max-device-width is deprecated as mentioned in the previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code section in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 630px) {
  .calculator {
    width: 60%; 
  }
  button
  {
    padding:16px 0px;
  }
}
```

`device-width` has been deprecated.
And to show all the `operator buttons` on all mobile device remove padding left and right from selector `button`.

[Have a look in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHdje.png)

Answer (score 1):

The device-width properties has been deprecated so use `min-width` instead. You can read on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width)

so change

- `min-device-width` to `min-width`
- `max-device-width` to `max-width`

```
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 630px) {
  .calculator {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
```